# Parsing jquery autocomplete multidimensional json data

Tags: jquery

I have a service that returns the following JSON used in jQuery autocomplete

```
[  
   {  
      "id":null,
      "houseNumber":null,
      "street":"2943 Iron Springs Pl",
      "city":{  
         "id":null,
         "city":"Castle Rock",
         "countyId":null,
         "stateId":null,
         "properties":null
      },
      "state":{  
         "id":null,
         "stateCode":"CO",
         "stateName":null,
         "counties":null,
         "properties":null
      },
      "zipcode":{  
         "id":null,
         "zipcode":"80109",
         "properties":null,
         "county":null
      },
      "propertyPhotos":null,
      "pid":"pUuQ8Oce"
   },
   {  
      "id":null,
      "houseNumber":null,
      "street":"2943 Magowan Dr",
      "city":{  
         "id":null,
         "city":"Santa Rosa",
         "countyId":null,
         "stateId":null,
         "properties":null
      },
      "state":{  
         "id":null,
         "stateCode":"CA",
         "stateName":null,
         "counties":null,
         "properties":null
      },
      "zipcode":{  
         "id":null,
         "zipcode":"95405",
         "properties":null,
         "county":null
      },
      "propertyPhotos":null,
      "pid":"ShDWSWcR"
   }
]
```

This is my js code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
            source : "/live-search",
            minLength : 1
        });
    });
</script>
```

when I try the code above, I can see the text box getting the results, but the results are empty. How can I format the results so it would show the addresses in the following format?

`street + ' ' + city.city + ', ' + state.stateCode + ' ' + zipcode.zipcode'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change your `source` attribute to:

```js
source: function(request, response) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        // "request" object has single property "term", which refers to the value currently in the text input.
        url: "/live-search?term=" + request.term,
        success: function(data) {
            response($.map(data, function(item) {
                return {
                    label: item.street + ' ' + item.city.city + ', ' + item.state.stateCode + ' ' + item.zipcode.zipcode,
                    value: item.id
                }
            }));
        }
    })
}
```

More info - http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source

Comment: I changed it, but it's not passing anything when calling /live-search It does not pass the term

Comment: I changed it to `url : "/live-search" + '?term=' + request.term,` and works nicely now